# Probability of Orphaned Blocks

Tags: litecoin, proof-of-work, algorithms, block-interval, stale-block

This is a question regarding the probability of orphaned blocks depending on the block interval. I am using Bitcoin vs Litecoin as an example.

Assuming equal hash rate and number of transactions, what is the relative increase in the probability of orphaned blocks for Litecoin, given that its block interval is a quarter?

The answer might be as simple as 4, but I'm wondering what is the quantitative justification?